# Android how call function after amount of time in loop

Tags: android, handler, runnable

I am new in Android programming, I used to program microcontroller, now I need a few assistance from you guys.
I want to call two function with delay after each function called repeatedly until the stop button pressed.

```
btnStart.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                //I want perform these series of function repeatedly
                //until stop button pressed
                while(true){
                    bluetoothDisconnect();
                    delay(3000);
                    bluetoothConnect();
                    delay(3000);
                    if(status == true){
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }

        });

        btnStop.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                status = true;

            }

        });
```

Big Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
  btnStart.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            status = false;

            Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    doLoop();
                }
            });

            t.start();
        }

    });

    btnStop.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
             status = true;
        }
    });
```

where

```
 private void doLoop(){
    do {
        bluetoothDisconnect();
        try {
            Thread.sleep(3000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        bluetoothConnect();
        try {
            Thread.sleep(3000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }   while (!status);
}
```

and `status` is a global variable, **FALSE by default** (declared as `boolean status = false`)
This code works as a simple solution, however I'd suggest you to look at the `AsyncTask` class:
 http://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html

Comment: it worked! thanks, but the stop button is not working, can you fix it?
and I have another thread that buffer the stream data from external device, and seems like i am not getting any from that thread, any idea how to resolve this?

Comment: @user3045529 yup, found a bug. Add `status = false` before the `Thread t = ...` I've edited the code, it works on my device, just've tested.

Answer (score 1):

You need to thread the code in btnStart otherwise it will lock the GUI. Sorry to not be more helpful, I write Android apps using Mono (C#), I am unsure how to do it in Java.

Answer (score 0):

Create an handler to delay the task .

Create the runnable thread and run your handler like:

```
Handler mhandler=new Handler();

Runnable  mRunnable=new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    bluetoothDisconnect(); 
             btnStart.performClick() ; 
                }

    };



btnStart.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            //I want perform these series of function repeatedly
            //until stop button pressed
            while(true){

                bluetoothconnect();
                mhandler.postDelayed(mRunnable,3*1000);
                if(status == true){
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

    });
```

Comment: hey, it is not working, i want bluetoothConnect() for 3 seconds then bluetoothDisconnect() for 3 seconds as well. And the btnStop not working, idk why?